# Button Activar Requiere o Include PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Necesito un botón que cuando haga click, se active un require.

Tengo entendido que esto puede hacerse solo con ajax, pero no sé exactamente como, espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

Comment: No se entiende del todo la pregunta.
Quieres activar un required en un campo de HTML? Por favor, escribe un ejemplo de lo que tienes y explayate un poco más en la explicación del problema

Comment: Estas confundiendo cosas. Un require o include nunca se pueden activar con Ajax ya que uno corre en el servidor y otro en el cliente. Probablemente lo que quieres hacer es cargar un trozo de página tras un evento. Para eso echa un ojo a las funciones `html` y `load`de jquery.

Comment: Pero dentro de este archivo tengo variables que con un requiere funciona, cuando las cargo por load estás no funcionan.

Comment: Creo que tienes problemas de base de conocimiento de PHP. Cuando tu haces una peticion al servidor al archivo a.php, el servidor 'ejecuta' ese archivo a.php. Si dentro de a.php tienes un include a b.php lo que hace es 'incustrar' b.php dentro de a.php por lo que cualquier variable en a.php estará disponible para el código de b.php. Sin embargo si en a.php no esta el include el servidor te devolvera el resultado de esa petición y si luego haces un load de b.php el servidor ejecutará solo b.php y nada de lo que se haya declarado en a.php existirá para b.php ya que a.php no entra en esa llamada.